# Reading properties from spark config file

Tags: apache-spark, sparkcore

I am trying to execute the following code

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName(“XYZ”)
  .getOrCreate()
```

However I am getting the following error 
    Error initializing SparkContext.
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your 
    configuration

```
The contents of my spark.conf are as follows
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed 
with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 
2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# Default system properties included when running spark-submit.
# This is useful for setting default environmental settings.

# Example:
spark.master                       local
# spark.eventLog.enabled           true
# spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory 
# spark.serializer                 
org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
# spark.driver.memory              5g
# spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value - 
Dnumbers="one two three"
```

I have also set the environment variable in my IntelliJ to spark.master = local .

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Note :

### I do not want to use the function .config("spark.master","local")

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and it worked for me. Did you renamed `spark-defaults.conf.template` to `spark-defaults.conf`?

While executing jar using spark-submit command, no need to give master URL in your code, it will pick from conf file. But when you are working with IntelliJ with "spark.master: local", that time it is not pointing to your installed spark. You have to make a jar and execute it using spark-submit.

Comment: I have renamed the file to spark-defaults.conf. However I am not executing it through spark submit. I am executing it through intelliJ . I guess that could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can set the master url from any of these listed in https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/submitting-applications.html#master-urls
 based on your setup.

Setting the master in the code

```
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .appName("Test")
  .master("local[*]")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Your solution works for me. However I do not want to use .master() function . I want spark to pick properties from my config file

Comment: @AmoghHuilgol SparkSession by defaults picks up master from spark-defaults.conf. Make sure you have the property spark.master                       local enabled in spark-defaults.conf therefore you might not need to set .master() function

Comment: Figured out the issue. Running code through spark-submit and intelliJ are two different things. When we run the code through intelliJ , the spark-conf file is not used by default. Hence added  -Dspark.master=local in VM options. This solved the error .